# Exception from barcode scanner with custom preview

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner

I'm currently using a `BarcodeScanner` with a custom preview showed in a `ContentDialog`.

I genuinely used the code provided on the Microsoft Documentation, and the thing is working right, but only once.

Here's my whole `BarcodeScanner` service class:

```cs
public class BarcodeScannerUtil : IBarcodeScanner
{
    private static Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeScanner _scanner = null;
    private static ClaimedBarcodeScanner _claimedBarcodeScanner = null;
    private static Action<string> _callback;

    MediaCapture mediaCapture;
    bool isPreviewing;
    DisplayRequest displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
    CameraPreviewDialog preview = new CameraPreviewDialog();

    public async Task ClaimScannerAsync()
    {
        string selector = Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector();
        DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

        if (_scanner == null)
            _scanner = await Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(deviceCollection[0].Id);

        if (_scanner != null)
        {
            if (_claimedBarcodeScanner == null)
                _claimedBarcodeScanner = await _scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();

            if (_claimedBarcodeScanner != null)
            {
                _claimedBarcodeScanner.DataReceived += ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync;
                _claimedBarcodeScanner.ReleaseDeviceRequested += ClaimedBarcodeScanner_ReleaseDeviceRequested;
                _claimedBarcodeScanner.IsDecodeDataEnabled = true;
                _claimedBarcodeScanner.IsDisabledOnDataReceived = true;
                await _claimedBarcodeScanner.EnableAsync();
                //await _claimedBarcodeScanner.ShowVideoPreviewAsync();
                await _claimedBarcodeScanner.StartSoftwareTriggerAsync();
                await StartPreviewAsync();

                Debug.WriteLine("Barcode Scanner claimed");
            }
        }
    }

    private MediaCaptureInitializationSettings InitCaptureSettings()
    {
        var _captureInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
        _captureInitSettings.VideoDeviceId = _scanner.VideoDeviceId;
        _captureInitSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
        _captureInitSettings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;

        return _captureInitSettings;
    }

    private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(InitCaptureSettings());
            displayRequest.RequestActive();
            DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            await new ErrorDialog("Impossible d'acceder à la caméra, veuillez vérifier les permissions de l'application.").ShowAsync();
        }

        try
        {
            preview.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            isPreviewing = true;
            ContentDialogResult resPreview = await preview.ShowAsync();

            //clic sur le bouton annuler
            if (resPreview == ContentDialogResult.Secondary)
            {
                await CleanupCameraAsync();
                await _claimedBarcodeScanner.StopSoftwareTriggerAsync();
                await _claimedBarcodeScanner.DisableAsync();
            }

        }
        catch (System.IO.FileLoadException)
        {
            mediaCapture.CaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatusChanged += _mediaCapture_CaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatusChanged;
        }

    }

    private async Task CleanupCameraAsync()
    {
        if (mediaCapture != null)
        {
            if (isPreviewing)
            {
                await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
            }

            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                preview.Source = null;
                if (displayRequest != null)
                {
                    displayRequest.RequestRelease();
                }

                mediaCapture.Dispose();
                mediaCapture = null;
            });
        }

    }

    public void Subscribe(Action<string> callback)
    {
        // it makes sense to have only one foreground barcode reader client at a time
        _callback = callback;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retire une action callback du BarcodeScanner
    /// </summary>
    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        _callback = null;
    }

    private async void ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync(ClaimedBarcodeScanner sender, BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        await CleanupCameraAsync();
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            preview.Hide();
        });

        if (_callback == null)
            return;

        var barcode = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, args.Report.ScanDataLabel);
        _callback(barcode);
    }

    private void ClaimedBarcodeScanner_ReleaseDeviceRequested(object sender, ClaimedBarcodeScanner e)
    {
        // always retain the device
        e.RetainDevice();
    }

    private async void _mediaCapture_CaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatusChanged(MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatusChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Status == MediaCaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatus.SharedReadOnlyAvailable)
        {
            await new ErrorDialog("Impossible d'acceder à la caméra car elle est utilisée par une autre application.").ShowAsync();
        }
        else if (args.Status == MediaCaptureDeviceExclusiveControlStatus.ExclusiveControlAvailable && !isPreviewing)
        {
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                await StartPreviewAsync();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm showing my preview I'm using `IsDisabledOnDataReceived = true;` but when I reopen my barcode scanner a second time, I get an exception saying `System.Exception : 'The request is invalid in the current state. Started'` at `await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();` in the `CleanupCameraAsync()`

That's really weird because when I click on the Cancel button of the `ContentDialog` showing the preview it's doing exactly the same thing and there's no problem after that.

I've been searching for an hour now and have no clue about what it could come from.

Comment: Didn't helped, same exception but I figured it out by myself, i'll add the solution in my post (even if it's a bit sketchy)

Comment: I found you have solved your issue, Please avoid post the answer in your original case, You could post answer below and mark yourself to convenient people who visit this thread later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer by myself :

I moved the `CleanupCameraAsync()` from my `OnReceived` event to my content dialog results

```cs
ContentDialogResult resPreview = await preview.ShowAsync();

//clic sur le bouton annuler
if (resPreview == ContentDialogResult.Secondary)
{
    await _claimedBarcodeScanner.StopSoftwareTriggerAsync();
    await _claimedBarcodeScanner.DisableAsync();
    await CleanupCameraAsync();
}
else
{
    await CleanupCameraAsync();
}
```

So when I close the dialog with the button it works, and if it closes by any other way `CleanupCameraAsync()` will still fire.

Plus, I added some lines in the `CleanupCameraAsync()` to reset all the components of my `BarcodeScanner`

```cs
private async Task CleanupCameraAsync()
{
    if (mediaCapture != null)
    {
        if (isPreviewing)
        {
            await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
        }

        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            preview.Source = null;
            if (displayRequest != null)
            {
                displayRequest.RequestRelease();
            }

            mediaCapture.Dispose();
            mediaCapture = null;

            /*******added these lines*********/
            displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
            preview = new CameraPreviewDialog();
            _scanner = null;
            _claimedBarcodeScanner = null;
        });
    }
}
```

It's not really clean but it forces the `BarcodeScanner` to have the default behavior everytime I call it.

If you have any better solution, let me know please.